# JdbcTemplate does not return a proper resultset. Why?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate

I am making a discussion board with Spring.

I am using `JdbcTemplate` to populate the articles of the users from the database, but the `JdbcTemplate's` `query` method does not return the proper `ResultSet`. Interestingly, when I copy and paste the SQL query from the code to SQL Developer, it returns the proper results.

The photo that shows the SQL query works,
[image]

JdbcTemplate code

```
public class ForumDao {
    private JdbcTemplate template;
    
    
    public ForumDao(DataSource dataSource) {
        template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    
    public Collection<ForumArticle> getArticleList(){
        Collection<ForumArticle> list = template.query("SELECT ARTICLE_ID, TITLE, NAME, VIEW_NUM, CREATED_DATE FROM MEMBER, FORUM WHERE MEMBER.ID = FORUM.MEMBER_ID", 
                new RowMapper<ForumArticle>() {

                    @Override
                    public ForumArticle mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        
                        ForumArticle article = new ForumArticle();
                        System.out.println("completeeeee--------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        article.setArticleID(rs.getInt("ARTICLE_ID"));
                        article.setTitle(rs.getString("TITLE"));
                        article.setName(rs.getString("NAME"));
                        article.setViewNum(rs.getLong("VIEW_NAME"));
                        article.setCreatedDate(rs.getTimestamp("CREATED_DATE").toLocalDateTime());
                        
                        return article;
                    }           

        });
        System.out.println("-dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd " + list.size());
        return list;
    }
}
```

All the configuration set-up is done properly and I am using Oracle DB. I have another DAO class for user data and its `JdbcTemplate` works perfectly.

When I run my code, the list.size() returns 0 instead of 4. It does not throw any exception.

What can be the possible solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line looks wrong:

```
article.setViewNum(rs.getLong("VIEW_NAME"));
```

`VIEW_NAME` should be `VIEW_NUM`, no?

What's probably happening is that when the above line executes, the code throws a SQLException due to an unknown column in the result set, which terminates the processing and gives you an empty result.

Comment: But the wired thing is the question said that it doesn't throw any exception.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem was the uncommitted DB...